# Duda sobre la declaración de variables dentro de un ciclo en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ciclos

He estado batallando por un micerable problemita que me ha surgido al momento de declarar una variable dentro de un ciclo for (incluso lo intente con un while y un do-while) y en cada iteracion darle un valor aleatorio con un objeto Random.

Lo que sucede es que al declarar el objeto random dentro del ciclo for, de este random solo podia obtener un valor con el metodo random.Next() y en las siguientes iteraciones no cambiaba a pesar de que se declaraba un nuevo objeto random, siempre era el mismo valor que se obtuvo en la primera iteracion.

Si tengo mi codigo con el random declarado dentro del ciclo for, el valor que obtengo del metodo random.Next() no cambia, siempre es el mismo que el que genero en la primera iteración:

```
        for(int x = 0; x < minas; x++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int fila = random.Next(0, celdas.GetLength(0) - 1);
            int columna = random.Next(0, celdas.GetLength(1) - 1);

            System.Console.WriteLine(fila+" "+columna);
            celdas[fila, columna].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;

        }
```

Pero si tengo mi random declarado antes de mi ciclo for, el valor que obtengo del metodo random.Next() SI cambia en cada iteración:

```
Random random = new Random();
        for(int x = 0; x < minas; x++)
        {
            int fila = random.Next(0, celdas.GetLength(0) - 1);
            int columna = random.Next(0, celdas.GetLength(1) - 1);

            System.Console.WriteLine(fila+" "+columna);
            celdas[fila, columna].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;

        }
```

No entiendo a que se debe este problema.

Answer (score 1):

> La generación de números aleatorios se genera a partir de una semilla, si la mimsma semilla se usa repetudamente, se generan la misma serie de numeros aleatorios, el constructor del `Random` toma la semilla del reloj del sistema para inicializarse.

El problema está en que cuando estas declarando el `Random` dentro del bucle `for` se esta llamando al constructor y este está cogiendo la misma semilla por lo que genera el mismo bloque de números aleatorios.

Por ello a los números generados "aleatoriamente" por ordenador se les dice que son pseudoaleatorios.